# how can i use a wildcard in Cleartool?

Tags: clearcase

I try to list my private files in Clearcase but i don't want to list all the files from all the folders, so i tried to use a wild card but without success.
I want only to list the private files in `src` folders.

- The structure of the folders is like `path1/to/src/` `path2/to/src/`
- I tried in cleartool the cmd `lsp -tag view_buildEnv .../.../src/...`

but the wildcard `.../.../src/...` does not return any results.
In config spec i use the same command `element .../.../src/... -none` and it is working properly.

How could i make it with success also with cleartool ?

Answer (score 0):

The main rules regarding wildcard (including ellipsis '...') are in "[**wildcards_ccase**](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/wildcards_ccase.htm)" (also detailed in "[`config_spec`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1&lang=en)")

[`cleartool lsprivate`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsprivate.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-4-109) works only in dynamic view.

> The Windows examples that include wildcards or quoting are written for use in cleartool interactive mode. If you use cleartool single-command mode, you may need to change the wildcards and quoting to make your command interpreter process the command appropriately.

So try:

```
cd/d M:\myview\myvob
# or
cd /view/myview/vobs/myvob

cleartool lsp -tag view_buildEnv ".../src/"
# or
cleartool lsp -tag view_buildEnv ".../src/..."
```

(you should not have to specify anything after `src/`: `lsprivate` should list all private elements under src and its subfolders).
(plus: "In non-config-spec contexts, the `...` pattern matches directory names only.")

If works well inside a vob, but might not work inside a view for multiple vobs.
In that case:

```
cd/d M:\
cleartool lsprivate | grep src
```

In batch file:

```
cmd /v /c "cd/d M:\; cleartool lsprivate | grep src"
```

Comment: It's not working, i have the error `Error: No match for wildcard`

Comment: Are you in your view inside a vob?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean ?

Comment: @poprock I have edited the answer to add the right path: you need to be in a dynamic view, and one folder below in a vob.

Comment: @Ok, but my concept is to call this command from make file to do a cleanup. I have to do for all VOBs a separate command ?

Comment: @poprock try it first in a regular shell command line, to see if that works. Then we will worry about a Makefile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103614/discussion-between-pop-rock-and-vonc).

Comment: ok, sorry, i see the warning from stack.

when i try `cd M:\f_01` the shell stays in `C:` , the view is mounted at M:

Comment: i am now in `M:\myvob` , but i have the error `cleartool: Error: ".../src/" is not a directory element.`

Comment: @poprock try `cd/d M:\f_01\<avob>` (replace `<avob>` by a mounted vob selected by your config spec: f_01 is *not* a vob. It is a view tag under which you would mount a vob. There is no such thing as `M:\myvob`. Only `M:\myview\myvob`.

Comment: i think in my clearcase f_01 is a VOB, i cannot go into my view at M: drive, only in mounted VOBS. The command `lsp` is working without the wildcard but listed all the private files.

Comment: @poprock No, it is not. It is a *view* tag. Check with `cleartool lsview` and `cleartool lsvob`. Also, in `m:\f_01`, do a `cleartool catcs` to see the config spec, which should show which vob this view expects.

Comment: With `lsvob` i have a lot of infos like this `* \f_01                \\log00002\vobstg\f_01.vbs public`

Comment: i made a mkview with putty command line and then i mounted the VOBS from the GUI.

Comment: What `cleartool pwv` returns when executed in `m:\f_01`? And what about that `cleartool catcs`?

Comment: `M:\f_01>cleartool pwv
Working directory view: view_buildEnv
Set view: view_buildEnv` and the `cleartool catcs` returns the whole of my config spec, a lot of rules.

Comment: @poprock yep, there is a setview. Don't. Try `cd M:\view_buildEnv\f_01`

Comment: @poprock when you mention `path1/to/src/` and `path2/to/src/`, are both `path1/` and `path2/` sub-folders of `f_01`?

Comment: @poprock then it won't work. Try instead `cd/d m:\; cleartool lsprivate|grep src` (using a grep command from https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)

Comment: thank you, i will try it tomorrow because now i m not at work! Thanx

Comment: @poprock No problem. see you tomorrow.

Comment: nice , it's working in command line but in batch file does not recognize `| OR` parameter.

Comment: what do you mean in cmd ? i wont to use it in make file and i use the `cmd` command in front of the cleartool cmd but cannot find the `| OR`  symbol. 
This is the whole of the command `@cmd /c FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %i in (\`cleartool lsp|grep src\`) do @echo "%i"`

Comment: @poprock just in case, try a `^` in front of the pipe `|` (it is not an `OR` operator, it is a pipe): ```(`cleartool lsp^|grep src`)```

Comment: it's not working , i have the message `| was unexpected at this time.
*** Error code 1
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "cleancode"`